# Debugging NameError: name 'NbrCicle' is not defined?

Tags: python, arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am trying to run the focal statistics tool on this raster for some reason I am getting this name error, even though the script ran fine a moment earlier.

```
FocStatCalc = arcpy.sa.FocalStatistics(MajFilCalc2, NbrCicle(3, "CELL"), "MAJORITY")
FocStatCalc1 = r"N:\geog327\python15\Project\Results\FocStatCalc.tif"
FocStatCalc.save(FocStatCalc1)
FocStatCalc2 = arcpy.Raster(r"N:\geog327\python15\Project\Results\FocStatCalc.tif")
```

Comment: You have a typo: NbrCicle should be NbrCircle

Comment: I am still getting the error after the typo was fixed

Comment: Have you import the module?: import arcpy and also: from arcpy.sa import *? Or you need to: arcpy.sa.NbrCircle(...

Comment: That solved it. It pretty strange that I had to do that even though at the beginning of the bigger block of code I have

    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial"), I just assumed I wouldn't need to import the sa tools again even if a license was already checked out.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: NbrCicle should be NbrCircle

Also make sure you have imported the modules:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
```

Or NbrCircle will not be recognized. You can also do:

```
arcpy.sa.NbrCircle(...
```